# <Webkit gtk> how to disable web security

Tags: ajax, webkit, cross-domain

Is there any way to modify in **webkit gtk** to **disable web security**? ( is the setting in WebKitWebSettings? or where?)

My purpose is to allow any cross domain request from app of my browser. I've already googled for a while . It seems a bug in webkit?

If it's not solved yet, why can I use google-chrome with --disable-web-security in cmd-line? Chrome is also webkit-based browser...

Any suggestion is welcome!!! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comparing webkit and gtk's source code, I found web security enable parameter is actually set in webcore ,but no responding function in gtk websetting. The only way to solve this issue is to modify gtk's source code and re-compile it.